# How to access WordPress database from Plugins file

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin and I want to access the database to get post data that are in published status. Any body help me in this matter.

Comment: Can we start by having the HTML and CSS that you have already?

Comment: While the screenshot is useful to display what you want, without your code we can only offer suggestions and guesses - neither of which are appropriate, or particularly useful. Please: Add the relevant code (the HTML and CSS) to your question, that way we might be able to offer something useful.

Comment: Sir I have submitted the php code